# Fading out right side of div

Tags: css

Anybody know why I can't get this linear gradient to fade out the right side of this div?

- http://jsfiddle.net/yykv5mLz/
- http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+72,ffffff+100&0+72,1+100

```css
.main a {
  display: inline;
}
.main {
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.fader {
  /* Permalink - use to edit and share this gradient: http://colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#ffffff+72,ffffff+100&0+72,1+100 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 72%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(72%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 72%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 72%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 72%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 72%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 */
  copy
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="fader">
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
    <a>Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you are confusing fading the div background with fading the text, which, maybe confusingly, does not work the same way.  Notice in your css that all of your gradients are happening in the **background** property.  This means only the background will fade, not the actual content like the text.  This is why in the previous answer changing to blue shows a gradient, the background fades from white to blue, in your case the background is white and fades to white, creating no effect.

If you want to fade the text itself, for what you want to do there is really only one option I'm aware of, and that is to create an overlay that fades to white, here is an example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahfws0d1/)

Basically you add another div *on top of* the one you already created and it creates the gradient effect with the following css:

```
.fade {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0) 30%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  position: absolute;
}
```

This has a potential downside of the text no longer being selectable by the user for copy/pasting, because it is underneath another div, however I don't believe there is any other way to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Because the gradients are going from white, to white, and the background is white... everything is white... You will never see the background gradient color. here is the code with a blueish gradient:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0) 72%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(72%,rgba(255,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0) 72%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0) 72%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0) 72%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0) 72%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yykv5mLz/1/